# Sound Engineering Algorithms

Tags: java, android, audio

I'm developing an Android app and the idea is to be able to manipulate sounds that the user loads. A few things I have in mind are:

- Formant
- Tuning
- Pitch Shifting
- Looping

I'm having trouble finding algorithms or code that I can reuse and modify. It seems to be an area that's not to common on the Internet.

Where can I find such code and algorithms?

Comment: can you suggest something on java related stuff?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), an open source sound editing program. It is written in C and C++, but I believe you can borrow ideas from its implementation.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'll check that out. I totally forgot Audacity was OS.